# Unity/C# Trigger Making something else dissapear

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

Im trying to make it so that when i trigger a trigger in Unity, it doesnt remove the trigger, but it does remove what the trigger is attached to. but i cant seem to figure out how to do it.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("pickup"))
    {
        audio.Play(); //Play it

        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText();
    }
}
```

This is an example of what im trying to do, but imagine it trying to set something else to inactive.

Comment: If you don't want to remove the trigger but want to remove the object it's attached to, then you'll have to find it's parent, store it, and then move the trigger up in the hierarchy before removing the object

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre and... how do i do this exactly?

Comment: If it's attached to the object you can do `this.transform.parent.gameObject` to get it's gameobject

Comment: Hmm.. im still not quite sure what to do. Sorry about that, im not a very fast learner. also, if i would be to remove the parent, wouldnt the child inside also just be removed?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve ? I think we could find a better solution to your problem than making some patch-up. Please edit your question to give us more details.

Comment: Alright, im making a game. this game is about a ball rolling around etc etc. anyways, im trying to make a script for a button so that the top layer dissapears when you stand on it, but reappears when you leave the trigger. but when i remove the top layer, it also removes the trigger, thus, its removed forever. this is what im trying to find a solution for. @MadJlzz

Comment: So if I correctly understand, the solution is not to deactivate the entire game object but only the physics and render parts. Your button should be associate with the target layer, get the `RigidBody` and `MeshRenderer` component, deactivate them in the `OnTriggerEnter` of the button and reactivate them `OnTriggerExit`

Comment: Hmm, i cant seem to find a way to disable it. If i try to use SetActive it doesnt work at all. and i cant seem to find anything online, either. @MadJlzz

Comment: For the `MeshRenderer` you should be able to do `Renderer.enabled = true|false` and for the `RigidBody` something like `Rigidbody.detectCollisions = true|false` plus `Rigidbody.isKinematic = true|false`

Comment: @MadJlzz Yes, but thats javascript, correct? So... how do i do it in C#. Also,  thanks for being patient for someone as dumb as me :/. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Here's the whole code: http://pastebin.com/LWBpt8sK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deactivate the game object, the attached collider will be deactivated too. If you want to deactivate a game object and let the collider exist you need to distinct between those two, i.e. have two game objects: one just for the collider and one for the actual object. now you can remove the actual object while the collider can continue to function.

The implementation depends on how you are handling the trigger.

### case 1:

OnTriggerEnter is written in a script attached to the game object which static collider (ground) is attached to.

> static collider is a collider without a rigidbody.

1. add a child to this game object and put the visuals in it (i.e. renderer or audio source).
2. add `public GameObject Child;` to the script.
3. set the reference of the child via unity inspector window.
4. deactivate the child instead of collider's gameobject in `OnTriggerEnter` method: `Child.SetActive(false);`

### case 2:

OnTriggerEnter is written in a script attached to another game object which also has a dynamic collider (ball) and a rigidbody.

> dynamic collider is a collider with a rigidbody.

1. add a child to the game object which the static collider is attached to
2. add a script to the game object (MyScript)
3. add `public GameObject Child;` to the script.
4. set the reference of the child via unity inspector window.
5. deactivate the child instead of collider's gameobject in `OnTriggerEnter` method: `(other as MyScript).Child.SetActive(false);`

Comment: the ChildGameObject doesnt seem to work. either that, or im just being stupid. could you explain?

Comment: Alright i got it to work. the thing i kept doing wrong is trying to put scripts on the ball itself, and not on the button. whoops.

Answer (score 1):

When you deactivate an object with `gameObject.SetActive(false);` you automatically deactivate every component on you object (`Renderer`, `Triggers`, `Scripts`, ...)

There is two options to achieve what you want to do:

- Use another object as a trigger (a Plane or a Cube and deactivate your object from this new object)
- Or as suggested by @madjlzz you can deactivate your Renderer and RigidBody

Comment: And how do i link a trigger to another gameobject? the way ive done it so far is to make a tirgger out of an object, and make that the parent of a gameobject